# Text manipulation with xstring failing: \@xs@StrRemoveBraces@@

Tags: errors, strings, xstring, text-manipulation

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand@firstchar}[1]{%
    \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\FirstChar]%
    \StrChar{\FirstChar}{1}[\FirstChar]%
    \FirstChar%
}
\newcommand{\mycommand@removespaces}[1]{\zap@space#1 \@empty}
\newcommand{\mycommand@lowercase}[1]{\expandafter\MakeLowercase\expandafter{#1}}
\newcommand{\makecode}[3]{\mycommand@removespaces{\mycommand@lowercase{%
    \mycommand@firstchar{#1}\StrRemoveBraces{#2}:\StrRemoveBraces{#3}%
}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makecode{First}{Second}{Third}
%should produce fsecond:third
\end{document}
```

What I am trying to do is to write a command that takes 3 arguments, keep the letter of the first one, combine it with the second one, adds a colon separator and adds the third parameter, while removing all the spaces and braces and making the whole thing lower case.

However the current code shown above fails to compile, and I don't understand why, and how to solve the problem.

Comment: `\MakeLowercase` doesn't return the lowercased argument, but the set of instructions to *print* the argument lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\MakeLowercase` doesn't return its argument in lowercase form, but rather the set of instructions for *printing* the argument lowercase.

You need an expandable version of `\MakeLowercase` and `expl3` comes to the rescue:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makecode}{mmm}
 {
  \vincent_makecode:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__vincent_makecode_word_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vincent_makecode:nnn
 {
  \vincent_makecode_process:Nn \tl_head:N { #1 }
  \vincent_makecode_process:Nn \tl_use:N  { #2 }
  :
  \vincent_makecode_process:Nn \tl_use:N { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \vincent_makecode_process:Nn
 {
  % store the lowercased argument for further processing
  \tl_set:Nx \l__vincent_makecode_word_tl { \tl_lower_case:n { #2 } }
  % remove braces and spaces
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\cB.|\cE.|\s) } { } \l__vincent_makecode_word_tl
  % issue the result, #1 is either \tl_head:N or \tl_use:N
  #1 \l__vincent_makecode_word_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\makecode{First}{Second}{Third}

\makecode{{Fi}rs{t}}{Se co{nd}}{T h i r d}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for completeness, an `xstring` version:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand@firstchar}[1]{%
    \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[\v@First]%
    \StrDel{\v@First}{ }[\v@First]
    \StrChar{\v@First}{1}[\v@First]%
}
\newcommand{\mycommand@remove}[2]{%
  \StrRemoveBraces{#1}[#2]%
  \StrDel{#2}{ }[#2]%
}
\newcommand{\makecode}[3]{%
  \mycommand@firstchar{#1}%
  \mycommand@remove{#2}{\v@Second}%
  \mycommand@remove{#2}{\v@Third}%
  \MakeLowercase{\v@First\v@Second:\v@Third}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makecode{First}{Second}{Third}

\makecode{{Fi}rs{t}}{Se co{nd}}{T h i r d}

\end{document}
```